# ¿como hacer que una funcion me devuelva 3 valores separados?

Tags: javascript, html, web, funciones, callback

¿De que forma podria hacer que 1 funcion me devolviera 3 valores para que de esa forma esos 3 valores me sirvieran de parametros de entrada de otra funcion(como si fuese un callback --Que de hecho, creo que lo es--)?

hasta el momento probe con lo siguiente(aunque no obtuvo resultado):

```js
var resultado;
function num_2(repet){
 for (var i = 0; i > repet-1; i++) {
  if (i>=1) {
   return i + ", ";
  }else{
   return i;
  }
 }
}


function sumarr(a,b,c){
 if (a!="" && a!=null) {
  resultado = a+b+c;
  return "\n" + "resul: " + resultado + '\n' + "1: " +
  a + '\n' + "2: " + b + '\n' + "3: " + c + '\n' + '\n';
 }else{
  return "noting";
 }
}
console.log("\n" + "callback: " + sumarr(num_2(3)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En javascript no se puede, lo que puedes hacer es retornar una estructura que te ayude con tu cometido, por ejemplo puedes retornar un array con los tres elementos o un objeto con tres propiedades.

Ejemplo retornando un array:

```js
function obtenerNumeros(){
  var numeros = [1,3,4];
  return numeros;
}

function sumar(a,b,c){
  return a+b+c;
}

var numerosSuma = obtenerNumeros();
console.log(sumar(numerosSuma[0],numerosSuma[1],numerosSuma[2]));
```

Ejemplo retornando un objeto:

```js
function obtenerNumeros(){
  var numeros = { 
    primero: 3,
    segundo: 5,
    tercero: 4
  };
  return numeros;
}

function sumar(a,b,c){
  return a+b+c;
}

var numerosSuma = obtenerNumeros();
console.log(sumar(numerosSuma.primero,numerosSuma.segundo,numerosSuma.tercero));
```